# C: Prefix __ before function

Tags: c, function

I have a question about why in some code is beeing used a prefix __ before function declaration? 
For example:

```
__irq void Timer0IRQHandler(){

T0IR=mMR0_INTERRUPT;    
ptrTimer0InterruptFunction();    
VICVectAddr=0x00;
```

}

and then:

```
VICVectAddr1  =(unsigned long)Timer0IRQHandler;
```

It is a form of type projection? Or it is only used in embedded programming? How it exactly works?

Comment: `__` prefix is reserved for the compiler. So each compiler will have its own keywords / functions named that way. If you check your compiler manual you will find what it does.  In this case you should look in the manual for `__irq`, which will be something like: the function declared with this keyword will be an interrupt.

Comment: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124968488.htm

Comment: C language implementations are *required* to prefix non-standard identifiers with an underscore.  The language standard demands it, it avoids accidental matches with identifiers in a program.  By convention, non-standard identifiers in the runtime library use a single underscore, in the compiler (like this irq keyword) use two.  It is non-standard because the C language spec has no formal support for interrupt handlers.  They are different because their machine code is unusual, normal ABI rules don't apply because of the need to rigidly preserve processor state.